# If anything than numbers inside textfield hide the submit button?

Tags: magento, textfield

I have multiple select and 2 text fields for advance multiple search in Magento eshop. The text field 1 has the value "Price Low" and the 2nd "Price High".

I want to disable the submit button until the user fills in only with numbers in the text fields, whose IDs are: "`searchbar`" and "`searchbar2`".

My problem is that if nothing is filled in the text field and the user submits the data, it will query "Price Low" & "Price High" text fields in the result and it will mess with the other values ("`brand`" etc).

Answer (score 1):

Magento forms already use [Really Easy Field Validation](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation) for Javascript so all you need to do is give those fields a `class="required validate-number"` and the rest is automatic.

However on the server side you <strike>should</strike> **must** validate all fields yourself if not for better searching then for security reasons. Remember the programmer's mantra; Garbage In, Garbage Out!